# Understanding the mean and rate of an exponential distribution

Tags: self-study, exponential-distribution

**Background:**

In the field of Civil Traffic Engineering the arrival of the vehicles in a road is random process modelled by exponential distribution [[1]](http://www.civil.iitb.ac.in/tvm/1111_nptel/531_HwayModel/plain/plain.html).

**Illustrative example:**

Along this line, let's consider the following example:
We have a road which is `800 m` long, and we have `X` number of vehicles (let's say `20`) moving at constant velocity `10 m/s`. If we want to have uniform distribution of vehicles in the road, we would need to insert a vehicle every `4 s`; Calculated by: `road-length`/`vehicle-velocity`/`number-of-vehicles` `=` `800`/`10`/`20` `=` `4`.

**Question:**

However, as it is given [here](http://www.civil.iitb.ac.in/tvm/1111_nptel/531_HwayModel/plain/plain.html) the distribution for such a scenario has to be exponential. What would be the interval for vehicle insertion, and more specifically the `mean` and the `rate` of the exponential function for the values given above:

- `road-length` = `800 m`
- `vehicle-velocity` = `10 m/s`
- `number-of-vehicles` = `20`

If you notice some poor explanation in my example due to misunderstanding of basic concepts please correct me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exponential refers to the time between cars. Instead of having the cars inserted exactly every 4 seconds, generate a random number according to the exponential distribution with mean of 4.

The density function of the exponential function is $f(t ; \lambda) = \lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ and defined for $t>0$. The mean of the distribution is $\frac{1}{\lambda}$. So use an exponential function with $\lambda =\frac{1}{4}$ and the random numbers you generate will have a mean of 4. In other words,  $\lambda=\frac{1}{4}$ will give us a rate of 1 car every 4 seconds. In general, if we want a rate of $k$ cars every $x$ seconds, we can set $\lambda=\frac{k}{x}$.

Depending on the software library you use, it is possible that the exponential function is defined as $f(t ; \beta) = \frac{1}{\beta} e^{-\frac{1}{\beta} t}$ where $\lambda$ was changed to $\frac{1}{\beta}$. If this is the case, then use an exponential function with $\beta=4$ and those random numbers generated will give a mean of 4.

Given a random number generator (between 0 and 1), you can [generate your own exponentially distributed numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Generating_exponential_variates) using $\frac{-ln(r)}{\lambda}$. In this case, create 20 random numbers between 0 and 1. Then for each number $r$, calculate $\frac{-ln(r)}{\frac{1}{4}}$ and you'll have 20 exponentially distributed numbers with mean=4 to use as your headway.

Lets look at a complete example. Say we have 20 cars travelling 10 m/s on 4 roads where each road is 800m long. Using a similar equation from the original question, this will give us a rate of

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{distance (m)} \times speed \Big(\frac{m}{s}\Big) \times totalCars (c) \times \frac{1}{roads(r)} &= rate \Big(\frac {c} {s \times r}\Big) \\
\frac{1}{800(m)} \times 10 \Big(\frac{m}{s}\Big) \times 20 (c) \times \frac{1}{4(r)} &= \frac {1 (c)} {16 (s \times r)}
\end{align} \\
$$

This a rate of 1 car per 16 seconds per road. To simulate this, generate 4 exponentially distributed random numbers with $\lambda=\frac{1}{16}$. This will be the time until the first car for each road. Then as each car enters the road, immediately generate another number to determine how long until the next car enters the same road.

Comment: I think they use the word `headway` to refer to inter-arrival time: _"An important parameter to characterize the traffic is to model the inter-arrival time of vehicle at a section on the road. The inter-arrival time or the time headway is not constant due to the stochastic nature of vehicle arrival."_ and when they classify the different `flows` they say: _4.A **negative** exponential distribution can be used to model such flow._ referring to `low flow`

Comment: @cross Thank you. I didn't realize "negative exponential" is another way to say "exponential". I have removed that comment and the comment about inter-arrival time. Also, I have added some more details about the exponential distribution to try and answer your questions.

Comment: one follow-up question. Is there a possibility to tweak the `mean` of the exponential distribution so that it influences the number of vehicles 1) **at any time** in a given scenario, or 2) as **mean number of vehicles** after `X` duration . Assume same scenario as above but instead of 1 road, having 4 roads...

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it would be easier to have `k` vehicles after `x` seconds. In the problem above, there is 1 car every 4 seconds and we use $\lambda=\frac{1}{4}$. With this more general problem, set $\lambda=\frac{k}{x}$. With 4 roads, I think it would be easiest to generate 1 random number for each road with $\lambda=\frac{k/4}{x}$

Comment: in that case, does the insertion into the roads has to be simultaneous  (one event inserts vehicles on each of the roads), random (one event insert to one random road) or round-robin (one event inserts to a certain road) -- Thanks in advance

Comment: ... just to clarify, by `X` duration, I meant the duration of the whole simulation process...now, if we compute `lambda`=`k`/`x`, where `k` - vehicles, and `x` - duration it looks like we totally ignore the effect of road length and vehicle velocity in the computation of `lambda`, while previously it was computed as `road-length`/`vehicle-velocity`/`number-of-vehicles`

Comment: @cross I have edited the answer to try and answer your questions. The rate of $\lambda=\frac{k}{x}$ is just another interpretation of the original computation.

Comment: @EricFarng can you consider a related question, where I change the point of view from exponential distribution of time, to a Poisson process: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164365/simulating-exponential-distribution-for-insertion-events